Ignoring a certain firebase crash report?
My application Firebase Crashlytics is being buried by this report

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start service com.myapppackage.android.MeNEMTjykwysdSGdtsw@afaad2b with Intent { cmp=com.sktbpf.gqvad.csdmqtsv/com.myapppackage.android.MeNEMTjykwysdSGdtsw }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.app.ServiceProvider.onStartCommand(android.content.Intent, int, int)' on a null object reference

It seems someone knows my application package name and created a new Android application that starts a Service within my application and causes crashes because Service is not supported or implemented in my app. I get a new crash report email every time they run their application.
My guess is they're using a box phone farm since I'm receiving multiple crash reports with the same error on various devices.
What can I do to resolve this situation? Is there any chance that I can make Firebase ignore such error?
